# define a method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How can i write a method called **sort_string** that accepts a string containing up to 26 unique alphabetical characters and returns a string containing the same characters in **alphabetical order**.

```
def sort_string
end
```

it will return:
sort_string( 'mezbah' ) # => returns 'abehmz'
sort_string( 'apple' ) # => returns 'aelpp'

Thanks,
Mezbah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a method that accepts an input:

```
def sort_string(input)
end
```

Managing the input type and constraints is up to you, you can either do with by doing nothing or throwing an exception. Some possibilities:

```
def sort_string(input)
  if input.kind_of? String
  end
end

def sort_string(input)
  raise ArgumentError.new "input is wrong" unless input.kind_of? String
end
```

sorting characters is yours to do too: a possibility:

```
def sort_string(input)
  input.split('').sort.join('')
end
```